# Facebook's Graph API's request limit on a locally run program? How to get specific data in real time without reaching it?

Tags: python, facebook, python-3.x, facebook-graph-api, facebook-like

I've been writing a program in Python which needs to have the datum of the number of likes of a specific Facebook page in real time. The program itself works, but it's based on a loop that is constantly requesting the number of likes and updating it on a variable, and I was afraid that this way it will soon reach the API's limit of requests.

I read that Graph API's request limit per user for an application is 200 requests per hour. Is a program locally run as this one considered an application with one user, or what is it considered?

Also, I read that some users say the API can handle 600 requests per 600 seconds without returning an error, does this still apply? (Could I, for example, delay the loop for one second and still be able to make all the requests?) If not, is there a solution to get that info in real time in a local program? (I saw that Graph can send you updates with a POST on a specified URL, but is there a way to receive those updates without owning an URL? Maybe a way to renew the token or something?). I need to have this program running for almost a whole day, so not being rejected from the API is quite important.

Sorry if it sounds silly or anything, this is the first time I'm using the Graph API (and a web-based API in general).

Comment: I think you need [this](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/webhooks)

Comment: i believe there is no webhook for the likes. you can only limit the amount of api calls so you don´t hit the limit.

Comment: @EvgenyKuzmovich yes I've read it, but I won't be able to have any accesible URL for using it (I don't own any public server and the program's going to be running on a computer connected to an open WiFi with no possibility of running a server there).

Comment: That, and what @luschn just said (I didn't realize that, so thank you for that!).

Comment: The details you’re asking about in regard to rate limiting: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/advanced/rate-limiting

Comment: @CBroe I know, that's why I posted this question, I'd like to know if there's a practical way to override the limitations described on that page in my specific case.

Comment: No, of course not. It would make the whole thing pointless, if anyone could just “overwrite” it at will.

Comment: ? I said override the limitations, not "overwrite" anything, I know I obviously cannot vary the number of maximum requests. I knew the request limit (I actually wrote the value in the post if you read it) and I think my question is pretty clear on the title (how can I get the value of a page's like **in real time without reaching the limit**).

Comment: Also (it isn't my main doubt, but I asked it on the title too), I wanted to know if the specified request limit applies to a local program, as that article you shared just deals with websites or applications within Facebook, if I understood it right.